# Contar el número de palabras que tengan vocales repetidas en una cadena

Tags: c

¿Cómo puedo contar el número de palabras que tengan vocales repetidas en una cadena?

Este el código que tengo:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(){

    char cadena[100];
    int i ,contador_a = 0, contador_e = 0, contador_i = 0, contador_o = 0, contador_u = 0, 
    palabras = 0;
    printf("Ingrese la primera cadena: ");
    fgets(cadena, 100, stdin);
    
    for ( i = 0; i < strlen(cadena); i++){/*Este bucle for  recorre la cadena 
 
    switch (cadena[i]){/*Con este switch se va comparando si la cadena tiene vocales

    case 'a': contador_a ++; break;
    case 'e': contador_e ++; break;
    case 'i': contador_i ++; break;
    case 'o': contador_o ++; break;
    case 'u': contador_u ++; break;
    }
    }
    if (contador_a  > 1|| contador_e > 1 || contador_i > 1 || contador_o > 1 || contador_u > 1){/*esta condicion es para que cuando uno de los contadores sea mayor que 1 a palabras se le sume un valor

            palabras++;
        }
    
    
    printf("El numero de palabras que tienen vocales repetidas en la cadena es : %d",palabras);
    
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: El título es un breve resumen del problema, ¡no el cuerpo de la pregunta! Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. ¿Qué problemas tuviste con tu código? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya que esto es una tarea, te daré una pista. Tal cual como buscas las vocales debes buscar el carácter espacio ' ', para determinar cuando termina una palabra.